# Raspberry Pi Camera live output presentation

Tags: raspicam, picamera

I am trying to setup a Raspberry Pi with Raspberry Pi Camera to output to the image local HDMI monitor. I can get that with raspivid -t 0.

However what I want to do is format that live video image to appear in a set location on the screen so it would appear to be inside a box on a image in the background?

I am not sure the best way to explain it hence the image example below. I would like the live feed to appear in the box in the centre of the screen.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I understand raspivid is probably not the right App. Any suggestions would be helpful.

[image]